# G.711 implementation A-law

Tags: c, standards, codec, standards-compliance

I am implementing the ITU-T G.711 standard and I decided to start with the reference code in G.191.

Running some tests on A-law compress made me doubt the correctness of the algorithm.

According to G.711, the input range 0-63 should be located on the first segment, with a step size of two. The sample code in G.191 maps this range as following:

- from 0 to 15 on segment 0 with a step size of 1
- from 16 to 31 on segment 1 with a step size of 1
- from 32 to 63 on segment 2 with a step size of 2

Not only we get a 1 segment offset when comparing the output to the value in the table, but the range is also halved, such that compressed FF corresponds to uniform 2047.

How should I proceed in order to have a G.711 compliant codec?

Comment: I'll be curious to see what kind of response you get to this. Seems like (although on-topic) an incredibly niche topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is commensurate with the standard.

Note first that the standard assumes 13-bit input (but always quantises the lsb), the code assumes 16-bit, and immediately discards all but the 12 msbs.  So in 12-bit terms, Table 1a in G.711 is really saying:

- Segment 1: input values 0 -> 31 (step-size 1)
- Segment 2: input values 32 -> 63 (step-size 2)
- ...

The only remaining discrepancy is that the first segment is apparently split in two in the code.  It's not really; note that the segments are not the same as exponents; Segment 1 encompasses both exponents `000` and `001`.  The code deals exclusively with exponents.